# Refactoring loop with conditionals

Tags: php

given a loop that sends an email to all subscriptions in an array

```
foreach($subscriptions as $s){
    if(!$s->send_email()){

    }
}
```

What would be the cleanest way to trigger a callback if all models have mailed successfully or show an error if one of the models fails to mail. Is it common to save all error messages till the end of the loop and print them as a whole, or break the loop with an error.

I'm using this in combination with a JSON REST API saving a project (/projects/1) which in turn emails all users.

The method I'm using now feels dirty with lot's of nested if else, sending 3 different response on different places

```
if($project->save()){
    $subscriptions = Subscription::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('planning_id' => $planning->id));
    foreach($subscriptions as $s){
        if(!$s->send_email()){
            $errors[] = "failed to send email. Subscription ". $s->id;
        }
     }
     if(count($errors) > 0){
          //send json api response with error response
     } else {
         //send json api success response
    }
} else {
    //send json api response with project error response
}
```

I was wondering what convention is concerning this

Comment: I think this depends how "serious" an error is ... do you want to stop after a single error or continue and report errors at the end - IMO this isnt a programming decision its a business one ...

Comment: This is not about "convention", it's about behaviour. What kind of behaviour do *you* want here - if a mail fails to send, do *you* want to break out and stop attempting to send any more, or do you want to attempt to send all mails and handle the errors later? I'm inclined towards the latter option in general, but it's all about how *you* want to handle it.

Comment: I think you are right. It just felt ugly, so I thought there should be a cleaner method, both solutions have their pro's and cons. Maybe there's another solution except the two I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little messy - and it combines multiple concerns within the "save" function - anyone reading the code needs to understand what "save" means, how we loop through the contacts etc.

I'd refactor it as follows:

```
if($project->save()){
    $subscriptions = Subscription::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('planning_id' => $planning->id));
     $errors = sendMailToSubscribers($subscriptions);

     $response = determineResponse($errors);
     // send JSON API response

} else {
    //send json api response with project error response
}

function sendMailToSubscribers($subscriptions){
  foreach($subscriptions as $s){
        if(!$s->send_email()){
            $errors[] = "failed to send email. Subscription ". $s->id;
        }
     }
   return $errors;
  }
function determineResponse($errors){
        if(count($errors) > 0){
          //return json api response with error response
     } else {
         //return json api success response
    }

}
```

Comment: I like it how you created a seperate response function. I think if you refactor it a bit more, you'd be there. 

$response = sendMailToSubscribers($subscriptions);
//$response being {"error" : "error message"} or the data itself
API::sendResponse($response);

And the let the api detect if there's a "error" in the object or just plain data. Based on that, perhaps set the header to 200 or 404/401/500 whatever

Answer (score 0):

You can use while logic so that failure falls through to the end of the block.

```
while(1) {
  if ($project->save()) {
    foreach($subscripts as $s)
      if (!$s->send_email())
        $errors[] = "failed to send email. Subscription ". $s->id;
  } else
    $errors[] = 'failed to save the project';

  if (empty($errors)) {
    //send success here
    break;
  }

  //send your errors here
  break;
}
```